# Can I put an <img> inside a <i> tag?

Tags: html

Would this be valid HTML?

```
<i><img src="image" class="myimage"></i>
```

Comment: If you ask for the semantics, what do you want to convey here? Why do you want to put `i` around the `img`? What type of image is this? And what is the context?

Answer (score 4):

As the `<i>` element can contain [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), and the `<img>` belongs to that group, it is valid.

Semantically (and with some common sense), if the only content is the `<img>`, no; if it contains both text and image, and the `<img>` is a natural part of the text, yes.

---

*The ship, [image], had many people aboard*

```
<i>The ship, <img src="galeon.png">, had many people aboard</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can put an `<img>` tag inside an `<i>` tag.
- No, it is not valid 'semantic-wise'.

For a complete explanation of the intended usage of the `<i>` tag, see the [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element)